# spl-token accounts -u mainnet-beta fails with error 429

Tags: spl-token

I try to get a listing of a wallet accounts using command

spl-token accounts -u mainnet-beta

and after a long delay (about a minute or so) it returns error 429:

HTTP status client error (429 Too Many Requests) for url (https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/)

And the same problem occurs with all spl-token commands causing the server interaction.

I tried to change my IP address using VPN, but it didn't help.

Although, solana CLI works fine with the same server.

What might be wrong?

Thanks
Alexey Guryev

Comment: Alexey, I am getting the same error as well as of 7am UTC Oct. 7th. Had no problems for months calling this endpoint, do we know if anything changed? I don't believe the rate limit criteria apply in my case as I am only making one request at a time.

Answer (score 3):

It's because [Solana mainnet-beta](https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/) RPC endpoint is rate limited.

From https://docs.solana.com/cluster/rpc-endpoints

> Rate Limits#
>
> Maximum number of requests per 10 seconds per IP: 100 Maximum number
> of requests per 10 seconds per IP for a single RPC: 40 Maximum
> concurrent connections per IP: 40 Maximum connection rate per 10
> seconds per IP: 40 Maximum amount of data per 30 second: 100 MB
>
> *The public RPC endpoints are not intended for production applications. Please use dedicated/private RPC servers when you launch
> your application, drop NFTs, etc. The public services are subject to
> abuse and rate limits may change without prior notice. Likewise,
> high-traffic websites may be blocked without prior notice.

You can temporarily use project serum RPC endpoint https://solana-api.projectserum.com by updating your config,

```
solana config set --url https://solana-api.projectserum.com
```

For production use cases you should be using your own custom Private RPC endpoints.